# Crm plugin update fails

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I have created two new fields named "Price" for quote and quote product and I want to update the second every time I update the first.

Here is my code:

```
protected void ExecutePostAccountUpdateContacts(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
if (localContext == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
}
string oldPrice = ""; 
string newPrice = ""; 

IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

var ServiceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
ITracingService tracingService = localContext.TracingService;

if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
    Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

    Entity preImageEntity = (context.PreEntityImages != null && context.PreEntityImages.Contains(this.preImageAlias)) ? context.PreEntityImages[this.preImageAlias] : null;

    // get the post entity image
    Entity postImageEntity = (context.PostEntityImages != null && context.PostEntityImages.Contains(this.postImageAlias)) ? context.PostEntityImages[this.postImageAlias] : null;

    if (preImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("Price"))
    {
        oldPrice = (string)preImageEntity.Attributes["Price"];
    }

    if (postImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("Price"))
    {
        newPrice = (string)postImageEntity.Attributes["Price"];
    }

    if (newPrice != oldPrice)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create query to get the related contacts
            var res = from c in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("Products")
                        where c["parentQuoteid"].Equals(entity.Id)
                        select c;

            foreach (var c in res)
            {
                Entity e = (Entity)c;
                e["Price"] = newPrice;

                ServiceContext.UpdateObject(e);
            }

            ServiceContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't asked a question, your query isn't quite right. So I am assuming your plugin fails when querying for `product` with a `parentquoteid`.

Not all linq operators are implemented, also , pass the entity logical name to the create query as a parameter, so instead of `Products`, just `product`. There is no out of the box field called `parentquoteid`, are you missing your custom attribute prefix?

```
var res = from c in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("product")
          where c.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_parentquoteid") == entity.Id
          select c;
```